# create a loop in random forest

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest

I receive some bits of advice from a friend about how to improve the model, but I can't follow this instruction very well. Would someone please help me to work it out? Below is my prediction model

```
    fit1 <- cforest(SWL ~   affect + negemo+ future+swear+sad
            +negate+sexual+death + filler+leisure + conj+ funct +discrep + i
            +future + past + bio + body + cogmech + death + cause + quant
            + future +incl + motion  + sad + tentat + excl+insight +percept +posemo
            +ppron +quant + relativ + space + article + age + s_all + s_sad + gender
            , data = trainset1, 
            controls=cforest_unbiased(ntree=500, mtry= 1))

     test_predict1<-predict(fit1, newdata=testset1, type='response')
```

My friend's advice:

You simply run a loop for e.g. 500 times. In each loop you create a temporary copy of the data.frame and then switch all the SWL values around randomly. Then you run the whole process on that messed up data.frame and finally save the total accuracy at the end. When it finishes you have e.g. 500 saved accuracies that you can compare to your best result.

Comment: `"that messed up data.frame"` ... spoken like a true brogrammer.  I don't completely understand your question, but randomForest package in R is fairly powerful and also fairly black box.  You may not need to do what you are doing.

Comment: So his suggestion is about producing a confidence estimate in how well our model is doing. He suggests running the model process many times and randomly reassign the self-report SWL score to each subject. So we would expect that a model built on the wrong SWL scores would produce a terrible result - but if we run this process many times we will be able to see the 'average random result' and we will be able to compare our 'best result' with that average to produce a P value for how significant our result is.

Comment: Well, you gotta choose your language for your audience. I thought 'perturbed' was less clear. 
I was suggesting that for a multi-step modelling process you could estimate the ability of a 'random classifier' by running a loop of the process but reassigning randomly the dependent variable. You can store the classification accuracy in each iteration and use the complete set to produce a distribution that you can then compare to your 'best' model (where the dependent variable was correctly assigned). at the end of the day you can estimate how much better than 'random' your model process is.

Comment: What is wrong with using the variable or Gini importance to assess how good the model is?

Comment: Although it's possible to assess the quality of the RF, I'm more concerned with showing the quality of the whole process. The data has been split into 3 uneven sized class-groups; the RF process has been split into 3 binary classification steps and each one has a threshold that might e.g. favour accurate assignment to the largest class and so on. So although the quality of the models at any stage may be good, I'm worried bias creeps into the composite process.